# What are the properties of the Rice University self-assembling wires?

Tags: nanoscience, experimental-technology

I've recently watched a video from Rice university, (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1d0Lg6wuvc&t=3s) where they used an electric field to remotely stimulate CNTs to form a wire. This wire was able to draw electricity directly from the field and could power 2 leds all by itself. This interested me, but I want to know more. Specifically, I want to know what exactly happens with the CNTs. They are nanoscale tubes, which are pushed together to form a wire. Similarly, fibers have already been spun from nanotubes, here the tubes are packed together, though not connected. They still are unique nanoscale molecules, just bundled together. Does the same thing happen in the Teslaphoresis experiment? Or do the tubes really form longer bonds? Are they a solid string one could take out of their petridish, or are they just loosely grouped together, like iron dust would be in a magnetic field? I just want some more information.

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://news.rice.edu/2016/04/14/nanotubes-assemble-rice-introduces-teslaphoresis/)?

Comment: Exactly! Sorry, I forgot to add the Link, so I'll do it now.